# can I pass a function a list index in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a 1920x1080 Numpy array where the value at each index is dependent on the index itself (for example Array[x][y] = f(x,y)).

I've been doing this so far with for loops, for example:

```
import numpy as np
xlength = 1920
ylength = 1080
def function(x,y):
    return(x**2+y**2)
indexarray = np.zeros((ylength,xlength),dtype = float)
for y in range(ylength):
    for x in range(xlength):
        indexarray[y][x]=function(x,y)
```

However, this is simply too slow for my purposes.

Is there a faster way to do this? I've tried using map() and numpy.apply_over_axes() to apply the function over a pre-built array where each array element is just a list of its x and y coordinates (like `Array[x][y]=(x,y)`), but I couldn't figure out how to make them work properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to [edit] the question to ask more clearly and directly. However, it's still not quite clear how best to help you. Could we see a corresponding example of the code you would try for the other approaches, and an explanation of what is wrong with the result?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710508 answer your question?

Comment: Tell us about the function.  Does it only accept scalar `x` and `y`.  If so, it has to be called once for each `x,y` pair.  `python `map` significantly faster than the for loop - and you'll need 2 maps.  Your example takes arrays, since it just uses operators, `**` and `+`.

Comment: The function I'm applying in my code takes the x and y indices of an array element and does some operations on them to convert it into a scalar (it actually does the x**2+y**2 and multiplies by a few constants) and then takes that number and does some corrections to make it between 0 and 2 pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applying functions on grids, use `np.meshgrid`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2


x = np.linspace(1, 1920, 1920)
y = np.linspace(1, 1080, 1080)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)


plt.contourf(x, y, f(xx, yy))
plt.show()
```

[image: meshgrid example]

The same can be achieved through broadcasting, but there are [other benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python-numpy) to using grids.

EDIT:

Using your function

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


twopi = 2 * np.pi


def phaseconvert(x, y):
    phase = x**2 + y**2
    floorcorrect = np.floor_divide(phase, twopi)
    return phase - floorcorrect * twopi


x = np.linspace(1, 1920, 1920)
y = np.linspace(1, 1080, 1080)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)


plt.contourf(x, y, phaseconvert(xx, yy))
```

[image: meshgrid 2]

Comment: Not really clear why you do phase - (phase / 2pi) * 2pi, fwiw.

Comment: thank you for your input. I need to do the phase - floorcorrect*2pi because the end result needs to be between 0 and 2pi (the application to this code is for some optics research where I need a specific phase shift on an incoming light wave, and subtracting a multiple of 2 pi from a phase is equivalent to the same phase)

Answer (score 3):

You talk as though `function` requires scalar inputs:

```
In [111]: xlength = 5
     ...: ylength = 6
     ...: def function(x,y):
     ...:     return(x**2+y**2)
     ...: indexarray = np.zeros((ylength,xlength),dtype = float)
     ...: for y in range(ylength):
     ...:     for x in range(xlength):
     ...:         indexarray[y,x]=function(x,y)
     ...:         

In [112]: indexarray.shape
Out[112]: (6, 5)

In [113]: indexarray
Out[113]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  5., 10., 17.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  8., 13., 20.],
       [ 9., 10., 13., 18., 25.],
       [16., 17., 20., 25., 32.],
       [25., 26., 29., 34., 41.]])
```

But it works just fine with arrays, for example with (6,1) and (5,) shape:

```
In [114]: np.arange(6)[:,None]**2 + np.arange(5)**2
Out[114]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
       [ 1,  2,  5, 10, 17],
       [ 4,  5,  8, 13, 20],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 18, 25],
       [16, 17, 20, 25, 32],
       [25, 26, 29, 34, 41]], dtype=int32)
```

Same as:

```
 function(np.arange(6)[:,None],np.arange(5))
```

There are lots of ways of generating the arrays for such a function. The other answer suggests `np.meshgrid`.

`fromfunction` takes a function and shape, and uses `np.indices` to create the arrays.  But it still does just one call to the function.

```
In [117]: np.fromfunction(function,(6,5))
Out[117]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  5., 10., 17.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  8., 13., 20.],
       [ 9., 10., 13., 18., 25.],
       [16., 17., 20., 25., 32.],
       [25., 26., 29., 34., 41.]])
```

`np.indices((6,5))`, `np.meshgrid(np.arange(6),np.arange(5), indexing='ij')` produce the same 2 arrays.  Also `np.mgrid`.

If the function really only accepts scalars, then you are stuck with some sort of iteration, one that calls it each time for each `x,y` pair.

Pretending `function` only works with scalars, we can use:

```
In [126]: f = np.vectorize(function, otypes=['float']) 
In [127]: f(np.arange(6)[:,None], np.arange(5))
```

This still calls `function` for each `x,y` pair.  For small examples, your iteration is faster, though for very large cases, this `vectorize` does better.  But don't use either if you can write the function to work with arrays directly.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Right now the function I'm applying in my code requires some additional computations:`def phaseconvert(x,y):
#position of a pixel to the desired phase shift for that spatial position.
    phase = (x**2+y**2)
    floorcorrect = math.floor(phase/twopi)
    phase -= floorcorrect*twopi
    return(phase)` could np.fromfunction still be able to do this calculation?

Comment: @JBowers yes, you would do `np.fromfunction(phaseconvert, (1920, 1080))` I believe. However I'd suggest taking a look at my answer, which doesn't require having to fiddle with broadcasting.

Comment: With the `math` function, you can only give it scalars.  But most `math` functions have `numpy` equivalents.